# poll() doesn't flag readable data

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, recv

I'm trying to write a network benchmark related to the Bufferbloat project.  Most of it works, but I'm having trouble reading a one-byte cancellation signal which is sent to a socket which is being written to continuously.

My first attempt was like this:

```
rv = send(sockfd, buffer, 65536, 0);
if(rv < 0) {
    printf("Hard shutdown of spew()!\n");
    goto bail;
}
if(recv(sockfd, &cancel, 1, MSG_DONTWAIT) == 1) {
    // other end asking us to stop
    cancel = 1;
}
```

Tcpdump showed the one-byte packet being sent by the client, but the server never responded to it.  Oddly, if I then terminated the client manually, the server would then respond to the cancel packet without hitting the "hard shutdown" path.

My next iteration was to use poll():

```
if(!poll(&pfd, 1, 120000)) {
    printf("Timeout in spew()!\n");
    goto bail;
}

if(pfd.revents & (POLLOUT|POLLERR|POLLHUP)) {
    rv = send(sockfd, buffer, 65536, 0);
    if(rv < 0) {
        printf("Hard shutdown of spew()!\n");
        goto bail;
    }
}

if(pfd.revents & POLLIN) {
    if(recv(sockfd, &cancel, 1, MSG_WAITALL) == 1) {
        // other end asking us to stop
       cancel = 1;
    }
}
```

This behaved identically to the earlier code.

What is going on, and how can I fix this?

Comment: How is your pollfd structure populated?

Comment: Also try checking for POLLERR explicitly and printing something if you get it.

Comment: Also, get the return code from every single function call and check it for error state and print the error if found. It can be surprising what failures you find when pushing the envelope.

Comment: struct pollfd pfd = { sockfd, POLLIN|POLLOUT, 0 };

Comment: Both of the above code fragments are enclosed within a while loop.  The client consumes all the data until the socket is closed, and this happens successfully at a rate of megabytes per second.

Comment: Aha...  it appears that it *does* get the command byte, and then blocks somewhere else.  In fact, it moves the problem to the client side.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the original code does in fact work.  The command byte is received, and the problem occurs immediately after exiting the loop.  The symptoms were confused by another factor.

Comment: Coming deliciously close to the classical 'Select isn't broken' meme